# Up/Down Click Counter

Tags: jquery, html, parsing, counter

Amazingly simple as it sounds, i'm having difficulty managing this.

Simply put, if i click an element with id "Counter" while the shift key is pressed, the int wrapped by Total should go up. If alt is held when clicked, it goes down.

```
$('#Counter').click(function(x) {
    if(x.altKey) {
        $('#Counter').html(parseInt($('#Total').html())-1);
    }
    if (x.shiftKey) {
        $('#Counter').html(parseInt($('#Total').html())+1);
    }
});

///////////

<div id="Counter"><span id="Total">100</span></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see your problem, you want to parse `<span id="Total">100</span>` into a number. You can't do this. Also you set the html of `#counter` to a number and so you loose `#Total`.

What you want, is:

```
$('#Counter').click(function(x) {
    if(x.altKey) {
        $('#Counter').html(parseInt($('#Counter').html())-1);
    }
    if (x.shiftKey) {
        $('#Counter').html(parseInt($('#Counter').html())+1);
    }
});

<div id="Counter">100</div>
```

Comment: It works in jsFiddle, but not in my actual code, even though its identical. http://jsfiddle.net/h2WXb/1/

Comment: Not sure what else i could provide.

Comment: It seems that a function i had that calculated a height value for a box, being live, was interfering with it? I moved this window function after this counter one and suddenly it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting the span tag, that's why it only works on the first click, after that there is no span tag with the id Total

Try:

```
$('#Counter').click(function (x) {

        if (x.altKey) {
            $('#Counter').html('<span id="Total">' + (parseInt($('#Total').html()) - 1) + '</span>');

        }
        if (x.shiftKey) {
            $('#Counter').html('<span id="Total">' + (parseInt($('#Total').html()) + 1) + '</span>');
        }
    });
```

or even more concise:

```
$('#Counter').click(function (x) {

        if (x.altKey) {
            $('#Total').html((parseInt($('#Total').html()) - 1));

        }
        if (x.shiftKey) {
            $('#Total').html((parseInt($('#Total').html()) + 1));
        }
    });
```